# Shell Script ( Twice Execution of a Single Query )

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I wrote a .sql script in Linux environment and I'm executing it in SQL*Plus but a single query in that is getting executed twice.

Script:

```
cat s2.sql

/* Global Name of DB */

 select * from global_name;

/*Database Status */

SELECT INSTANCE_NAME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS FROM V$INSTANCE;
```

Output:

```
SQL> @ s2.sql

GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xyz


GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xyz


INSTANCE_NAME    STATUS       DATABASE_STATUS
---------------- ------------ -----------------
xyz           OPEN         ACTIVE
```

I tried it with both the extension .sql and .txt though I'm getting the same results.

Why is it doing that, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the second comment. The line:

```
/*Database Status */
```

is being interpreted as [a buffer-submitting `/`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm#SQPUG162), not as a comment at all. If you add a space to match the other one:

```
/* Database Status */
```

then it will be correctly seen as a comment, and won't cause the second invocation of the statement.

The behaviour you're seeing is actually [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref417), sort of - indirectly:

> You must enter a space after the slash-asterisk(/*) beginning a comment.